# What is the name of the inverse of coordinate isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

Let's say we have vector space $V$ and some fixed ordered base $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $V.$ We can then associate to this base isomorphism $F:V\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and its inverse $F^{-1}=\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to V.$

[Wiki article about change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Preliminary_notions) states that $\phi$ is called **coordinate isomorphism**.

Are there any names of $F$ and $\phi$ in literature?

Comment: To my knowledge: no.

Comment: I believe the name can be used for one or the other depending on the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there isn't any standard notation or a name but a popular notation for $F(v)$ is $F(v) = [v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ (where $\mathcal{B} = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is the ordered basis of $V$) and $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is often called the **coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$**. When applied consistently to include matrix representation of linear maps, it has nice "cancellation properties" that makes various isomorphisms easy to remember such as

$$ [T]_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{B}} [v]_{\mathcal{B}} = [Tv]_{\mathcal{C}} $$

(the coordinate vector of $Tv$ with respect to the ordered basis $\mathcal{C}$ is the product of the matrix $[T]_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{B}} $ representing $T$ with respect to an ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$ in the domain and $\mathcal{C}$ in the codomain with the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and the $\mathcal{B}$'s cancel out).

The map $\phi$ usually doesn't get a name but since choosing an ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ of $V$ is the same as giving an invertible linear map $\phi \colon \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow V$ (any ordered basis determines $\phi$ uniquely by requiring that $\phi(e_i) = v_i$ where $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ is the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$ and any such map determines $v_i = \phi(e_i)$), sometimes people just identify the ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$ with $\phi$ and call $\phi$ "a choice of an ordered basis".

Comment: I was susspecting that this is the case. Great that you wrote is so clearly.